# Replace excel rows from another sheet where column value matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have 2 sheets with matching columns where the first column in each sheet contains a key. Sheet 2 contains some of the rows in sheet 1 with updated data. How can I replace the rows in sheet 1 with those in sheet 2 if there is a matching key.

**Example Sheet 1**

| KEY | NAME | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Bob | Seattle |
| 124 | Steven | Chicago |
| 125 | Tom | San Diego |

**Example Sheet 2**

| KEY | NAME | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Bob Doe | New York |

**New Sheet 1**

| KEY | NAME | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Bob Doe | New York |
| 124 | Steven | Chicago |
| 125 | Tom | San Diego |

I'm not sure if this is something that can be done via VLOOKUP or if I should create a script for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update Worksheet

**Destination/Source Initial**

[image: Initial]

**Destination Final**

[image: Result]

**In a Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateWorksheet()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const CritCol As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = wb.Worksheets(sName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    If scrg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data in the source worksheet.", _
            vbCritical, "Update Worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = scrg.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = scrg.Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    Dim scData As Variant
    If srCount = 1 Then
        ReDim scData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): scData(1, 1) = srg.Columns(CritCol).Value
    Else
        scData = srg.Columns(CritCol).Value
    End If
    
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = wb.Worksheets(dName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    If dcrg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data in the destination worksheet.", _
            vbCritical, "Update Worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dcrg.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dcrg.Resize(drCount).Offset(1)
    Dim dData As Variant: dData = drg.Value

    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = drg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim rValue As Variant
    Dim rIndex As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To drCount
        rValue = dData(r, CritCol)
        If Len(rValue) > 0 Then
            rIndex = Application.Match(rValue, scData, 0)
            If IsNumeric(rIndex) Then
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    dData(r, c) = sData(rIndex, c)
                Next c
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    drg.Value = dData
    'drg.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    'wb.Save

    MsgBox "Worksheet updated.", vbInformation, "Update Worksheet"
            
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Excel 2019 or below**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A2:C3,MATCH(INDEX(Sheet1!A2:C5,,1),INDEX(Sheet2!A2:C3,,1),0),{1,2,3}),Sheet1!A2:C5)
```

This is an array formula, so if your excel is before 2016, this has to be entered with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

For **Excel 365**, you can do this easier to modify formula:

```
=LET( st, Sheet1!A2:C5,
      ct, Sheet2!A2:C3,
       skeys, INDEX( st,, 1), ckeys, INDEX( ct,, 1),
       IFERROR( INDEX(ct,MATCH( skeys, ckeys, 0 ),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(st))), st )
      )
```

where you place your starting table from Sheet1 into the variable **st** and your correction table into the variable **ct**.  It can be entered into the upper left corner of your New Sheet table and it will spill out to complete the result automatically as shown in the screenshot below.

I had to extend your table to test it, so I used:

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

**NewSheet**

[image]

Comment: There is no `LET` in `Excel 2019`.

Comment: wow - you're right. I thought it was in 2019 because it was released at that time - seems the same is true for SEQUENCE.

Comment: Thanks - I removed that reference. I also saw that I had a variable still left in place from testing and removed that. Also, I misspelled Broussard, so I fixed that. ;-)